# WEBSITES_PORT doesnt change the docker port Azure

Tags: azure, docker, websocket

I added `WEBSITES_PORT` : `80` to my application settings on Azure app services but docker still runs on port 8080. Any ideas?

```
2020-05-21T13:31:00.928Z INFO  - Starting container for site
2020-05-21T13:31:00.928Z INFO  - docker run -d -p 3175:8080 --name triverserver-50_0_23178de4 -e WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION=12-lts -e APPSETTING_WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION=12-lts -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=TriverServer-50 -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=triverserver-50.azurewebsites.net -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=3935d26f58841e3917f2e00f0df6da5c8b0d6cb2f1f0c9e9c490026921b7ee2e -e HTTP_LOGGING_ENABLED=1 appsvc/node:12-lts  

2020-05-21T13:31:04.331Z INFO  - Initiating warmup request to container triverserver-50_0_23178de4 for site triverserver-50
2020-05-21T13:31:19.540Z INFO  - Container triverserver-50_0_23178de4 for site triverserver-50 initialized successfully and is ready to serve requests.
```

Comment: What's the port set to in your Dockerfile?

Comment: Not sure where I can find that on Azure.

Comment: `WEBSITES_PORT` is here to map the port use by your docker container to a port controlled by the App Services. What is the port your docker container use? It's like it exposed the port 8080 as the log try to map it `docker run -d -p 3175:8080 `

Comment: Yeah the docker is using 8080, I'd like to have traffic on that forwarded to the 80 of my app

Comment: What you need to do is to set the WEBSITES_PORT with value 8080, not 80. It will map your docker port 8080 to 80.

Comment: WEBSITES_PORT would work with WebApp for Containers, where you would use a Custom Docker Image. As per the docker run command, it seems that you've deployed the nodejs application on a Linux App Service - where WEBSITES_PORT wouldn't work. You could try using PORT environment variable. I'd suggest changing the application to use the PORT environment variable:

const port = process.env.PORT || 1337;
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/nodejs-docs-hello-world/blob/master/index.js#L8